# Is there a way to view the full content of notifications?

Tags: 8.1, 8.0, notifications

When in areas with poor mobile internet, often my phone will receive notifications (about new facebook posts or messages typically) but the app itself cannot load the message.

The notification will typically say "Steve commented on your post "Well, ..." and then be cut off by the size of the screen. If I could just see the notification text in full, this would be very useful.

Is more information present than is shown on the screen, and is there any way to explore my notifications in more detail... some app or setting perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is more information present than is shown on the screen?

Yes. The app passes in the full notification, but the system is truncating it, which is what you're running into.

There is no way around this in Windows Phone 8 or 8.1. However, Windows 10 Mobile allows you to expand the notification, showing much more -if not all- of it.

You can see an example here:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's so frustrating the information is there but can't be viewed. You sound like you're a developer - do you know if this information is even exposed in a way that a 3rd-party app could view, or is this private OS data?

Comment: Did a little looking here and I don't think it's possible for an app to access another app's notifications since this could lead to huge security problems; imagine if a seemingly innocent app could hijack your WhatsApp notifications and forward them to goodness-knows-where.

Comment: Ok, in addition to my previous comment: I tried doing it here using the `ToastNotificationManager` class and it doesn't seem possible. You can only access your app's notifications. Looks like it's also been tried here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533070/get-all-windows-8-10-toast-notifications

Comment: Oh well - thanks very much for looking into this!